# How to update data from Firebase Database without restarting Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can get data from Firebird DataBase but they are updated only if I restart the activity how to do it without restarting the activity.

The code snippet with the implementation of retrieving data

```
 ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                long coinsAmount = dataSnapshot.child("coinsAmount").getValue(Long.class);
                text.setText(String.valueOf(coinsAmount));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    };
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

to:

```
uidRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

This way, your listener will be called each time the value in the DB changes,
 and not only once.

Read more about [difference between valueEvent and singleValueEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579000/difference-between-addvalueeventlistener-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. using `addValueEventValueListener` also restarting activity every time there is an update in the db

Comment: The listener doesn't restart the activity, it seems that your case is different than the question's