# Role base login with Firebase database is failing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing a project called e-school. It has 4 types of users which uses Firebase authentication and Firebase realtime database to login to their accounts, Anyway, I'm getting issues while working with Firebase realtime database and Firebase authentication. I'm letting users to their respective dashboards comparing the authentication data with the realtime database.

//Registration Code

```
     auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    Users user = new Users();
                    user.setE_mail(email.getText().toString());
                    user.setNumber(Phone.getText().toString());
                    user.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

                    user.setU_name(username.getText().toString());

                    users.child("principal").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Registration Success",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            return;
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Registration Failed: "+e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            return;

                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed :"+e.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

//Login COde

```
     auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(t_email.getText().toString(), t_password.getText().toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                             id = auth.getUid();
                            teacherValidation(id);




                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Authentication Failed", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

//TeacherValidate

```
     private void teacherValidation(final String id) {

    users = db.getInstance().getReference("Users/teachers");

    users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(id)){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," "+id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, teachers.class);
                    it.putExtra("UID", id);
                    startActivity(it);
                    finish();

            }else{

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Teacher Esxist With the Given Credientialss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace of your issues?

Comment: when i start logging into the app it says "no teacher exists with the given credientials"  i guess i am unable to do the login logic correctly

Comment: That's true man. It looks like you're being able to communicate with the login service, but simply the authentication parameters are not satisfying the request.

Comment: 09-30 17:04:41.014 8160-8175/com.jupitor.samelogin D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( ysiE1uqV7sax7QqMbn5050jfnPI3 ).

Comment: here is the log its getting the uid from teacher's node which is (ysiE1uqV7sax7QqMbn5050jfnPI3 ) but not comparing it any solution

Comment: Yeah, I think you don't need 'addValueEventListener', because you're not changing any information in the database. Instead of getting the whole users' list from 'getReference' with "Users/teachers", just try getting the specific user with "Users/teachers/ysiE1uqV7sax7QqMbn5050jfnPI3"

Comment: there are currently 10 teachers registered in "Users/teachers" should i use the same for each & the id is different for every single teacher.

Comment: can you please comment me a sample code for this... and thank you for your time

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities)** out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to get all teachers details on client side. Instead you can directly check in database for that user, it'll increase the performance of app also.

Just modify `teacherValidation` method like this.

```
private void teacherValidation(final String id) {

    users = db.getInstance().getReference("Users/teachers").child(id);

    users. addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        // If below condition checks true, 
        // that means user exists on teacher node, so probably he/she is a teacher.
        if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," "+id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, teachers.class);
                it.putExtra("UID", id);
                startActivity(it);
                finish();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Teacher Exist With the Given Credientialss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
      });
}
```

Comment: This COde WOrked FOr Me THankew You Much

Answer (score 0):

I got this code snippet. Probably `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is your method.

Pay special attention in the way the query is built, calling a first child which is the table called "users" and then a second child which is a user with a specific userId. FUser is equivalent to your Users class.

Try it...

```
    private void getFirebaseUserInfo(final String userId, final GetUserInfoListener userInfoListener) {

    DatabaseReference userIdReference = getDatabaseReference().child("users").child(userId);
    userIdReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            try {
                final Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(FUser.class);
                if (!user.email.isEmpty()) {
                    // Do whatever
                } else {
                    userInfoListener.onSuccess(user);
                }

            } catch(DatabaseException e) {
                userInfoListener.onFailure(new Exception(e.getMessage()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            userInfoListener.onFailure(new Exception(databaseError.getMessage()));
        }
    });
}
```

Also, look at the difference:
[Difference between addValueEventListener() and addListenerForSingleValueEvent() of firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579000/difference-between-addvalueeventlistener-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent)