# Why are Both if and else statements executed in datasnapshot?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, firebase-realtime-database

I am checking for a child in the firebase database using the code below

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child.("cook").child(userID);
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," child is present ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                logins();
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error,  ensure you have internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

If the child is present a toast is made child is present, if not the logins() method is called however, both the the toast and method logins() is called. The toast happens first and later on the method is called

Comment: Sounds like `onDataChange` gets called twice.

Comment: Add your database structure

Comment: @T.J. Crowder if that's the case how do I fix that?

Comment: If you don't want it repeatedly called, then attach a different listener to check only once https://stackoverflow.com/a/41579337/2308683