# Realtime database update same object on continuously button click

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The first click in the button was has been already subtracted.
For example the value inside the button is 3 it became 2 after clicking.
How to reduce value in every click you made in the button?

```
String uid = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    uidRefItem = databaseReference.child("UserItem").child(uid);
```

Here inside of the button.

```
uidRefItem.child("TimerAddOnemin").setValue(getTimerAdd - 1);
```

On my second click the value on database didn't update only on first click.

Comment: You should use `.setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));` and `.setValue(ServerValue.increment(-1));`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use:

```
      addValueEventListener()
```

Instead  of :

```
     addListenerForSingleValueEvent()
```

for more info check :[Difference between addValueEventListener() and addListenerForSingleValueEvent() of firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579000/difference-between-addvalueeventlistener-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent)

Comment: `addValueEventListener()`
yup already use it.
then I use this part `.setValue(ServerValue.increment(-1));` to continuously subtract on button click