# How to get the Child in Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to perform `login` operation in my app using `firebase` my `Users` node is something like:

[image: my model]

```
mUserCompounds.orderByChild("email").equalTo("test@gmail.com").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

i want to get that complete `object` with which i have matched the name. so that

i can also compare password etc.
Thanks for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017765/retrieving-child-value-firebase refer this

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared? What does it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: dear i want to get the test object so that i can use image, pointsTotal and other values. All i know about User is his email and password on the basic of email and password i want to fetch complete object.

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to get the values of the node "test" in order to compare them with other values?

Comment: @Lucem dear i have two values email and password on the basis of this info i want to get the complete record that is "test" node and all its  child values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit the Firebase documentation 
[enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

[read firebase data](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/firebase-realtime-database-android-tutorial)
Also always push data to firebase with Pushkey so you can get whole object.

Comment: i have a key named as test under Users node.

Comment: No you have to push object using push key.

Comment: code example :                                                            
 `DatabaseReference postsRef = ref.child("posts");
DatabaseReference newPostRef = postsRef.push();
newPostRef.setValue(new Post("gracehop", "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"));

// We can also chain the two calls together
postsRef.push().setValue(new Post("alanisawesome", "The Turing Machine"));`

Answer (score 1):

this is pretty simple

```
mUserCompounds.orderByChild("email").equalTo("test@gmail.com").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        Log.i("your tag",""+dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First make a pojo class of User data .

```
Class User {
 String about;
 String email;
 String image;
 String name;
 String password;
 String pointsTotal;
 String totalTasksDone;
}
```

Make getter setters and define constructors.

```
mUserCompounds.orderByChild("email").equalTo("test@gmail.com").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                         //User already exists
                         User user1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); 
                         System.out.println(user1.getPassword());
                       }
                  }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```