# How do I parse through this firebase datastructure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How do I parse through this database and get all the double values. Help me

Comment: are you using node js to query in firebase ?

Comment: nope java in android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `DRIVERID` is a direct child of your Firebase root, to get those values, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("DRIVERID").child("LatLng");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double Lat = dataSnapshot.child("Lat").getValue(Double.class);
        double Lng = dataSnapshot.child("Lng").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", Lat + " / " + Lng);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
22.582798 / 88.35998
```

To get also the `Compass`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("DRIVERID");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double Compasss =  = dataSnapshot.child("Compasss").getValue(Double.class);
        double Lat = dataSnapshot.child("LatLng").child("Lat").getValue(Double.class);
        double Lng = dataSnapshot.child("LatLng").child("Lng").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", Compasss + " / " + Lat + " / " + Lng);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
54.5750122070312 / 22.582798 / 88.35998
```

The line of code that worked for the OP is:

```
HashMap Compasss = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.parseBoolean("Compasss"));
```

Comment: Thanks alex ..this works.....what about the compass values??

Comment: Got an error   
 `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Double to String`
on this line: `String Lat = dataSnapshot.child("LatLng").child("Lat").getValue(String.class);`

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: I am logging only the compass values that too is null....I am running your updated code

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Just removed `.child("LatLng")`. See again please. It's ok now?

Comment: nope it is not working....

Comment: Changed `long` to `double`.  Sorry but i'm wrtting from my phone. Does it work now?

Comment: `String Compasss = dataSnapshot.child("Compasss").getValue(String.class);
                double Lat = (double) dataSnapshot.child("LatLng").child("Lat").getValue();
                double Lng = (double) dataSnapshot.child("LatLng").child("Lng").getValue();
                Log.d("TAG", Compasss + " / " + Lat + " / " + Lng);`


lat and lon are coming but compass is still null 
Log: `D/TAG: null / 22.5826983 / 88.3589983`

Comment: because you still need to change this line `String Compasss = dataSnapshot.child("Compasss").getValue(String.class);` with `double Compasss = (double) dataSnapshot.child("Compasss").getValue();`

Comment: What about now?

Comment: it's causing an error
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference`

maybe because compass does not have a child

Comment: Try to use `.getValue(Double.class)` and not `(double)`. See my exact code o have provided you.

Comment: still the virtual method on a null object error alex

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your code and a new screenshot of your database that includes also the root.

Comment: `HashMap Compasss = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.parseBoolean("Compasss"));`
               
`Compasss.get("Compass");` worked!! anyways thanks for your help alex...update your code there...I will upvote as soon as I get 15 rep.

Comment: Just edited my answer again. Is something strange with this line but glad it worked for you. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers alex!....try that if you get time and please do explain the code because I just pressed alt+enter and it worked.  lol

Answer (score 0):

querying firebase with named node like `DRIVERID` in your case will be passing the child name after getting the refernce to `DRIVERID` node.

```
firebaseRefTODRIVERID.child("Latlng").once("value", snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
})
```

you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017765/retrieving-child-value-firebase)

Comment: I'm a newbie so I hope I make some sense... I am using java in android studio...from what I found I'm supposed to do something like this..
 `for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
 { lat = (double) snapshot.child("Lat").getValue(); 
   lon = (double)  snapshot.child("Lon").getValue();
  compass = (double)  snapshot.child("Compass").getValue();
  }`
but obviously the compass value needs to be parsed differently...I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating 2 Java classes:

- Location(double Lat, double Lng);
- Driver(String Compass, Location LatLng)

Then you'd be able to get this using:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DRIVERID");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Driver driver = datasnapshot.getValue(Driver.class);
        //your data would be stored in this driver variable
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```