# ValueEventListener on firebase database in flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I am learning android app development in flutter.
I have started from flutter chat app example. In the [Enable data syncing](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#8) section , It is explained to use Firebase Database like below.

`final DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('messages');`

Also the `push()` and `set()` methods are working fine.

When i try to listen to events on child  using `ValueEventListener`.
The `DBreference` created above has no methods like `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` or `addValueEventListener`.

My main goal is to retrieve value of child as expalined in SO answers 
[Retrieving child value -firebase-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017765/retrieving-child-value-firebase)
 or [Checking if a particular value exists in the firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893328/checking-if-a-particular-value-exists-in-the-firebase-database?rq=1)

I m getting  `undefined class ValueEventListener`
if i create a new `ValueEventListener`, i tried by importing

`import 'com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener';`

I m unable to import this path as well.
Same error for `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` or `addValueEventListener`.

I am using android studio 3.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
var subscription = FirebaseDatabase.instance
.reference()
.child('messages')
.onXxx
.listen((event) {
  // process event
});
```

where `onXxx` is one of

- `value`
- `onChildAdded`
- `onChildRemoved`
- `onChildChanged`

To end the subscription you can use

```
subscription.cancel();
```

Comment: I get the error  `The method 'listen' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference'.`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the reference to a specific event. I added `onXxx` where it's missing. I'll updat when I'm back on my computer with the correct name.