# How to use values from firebase database?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-realtime-database

I have values in Firebase database and I just want to have it as a int variable.

[image]

I want to have coinsAmount in a variable in the project.

I was looking for a lot of information but could not understand because most of the information in English and I do not fully understand the translation of Google translator please tell me how to do it or throw off where it is written please

```
 ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int coinsAmount = dataSnapshot.child("coinsAmount").getValue(Long.class);
        text.setText(coinsAmount);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
   uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

`int coinsAmount = dataSnapshot.child("coinsAmount").getValue(Long.class);` says:

> Incompatible types. Required int but 'getValue' was inferred to T: Incompatible types: Long is not convertible to int

```
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

says:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'addListenerForSingleValueEvent

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpU7n.png

initializing in activity

```
public class MenuActivity extends BaseActivity {
public TextView text;
private static final String TAG = "MenuActivity";
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(getUid());
```

Comment: I understand that this may be a very stupid question, but please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017765/retrieving-child-value-firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of your `coinsAmount` property, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long coinsAmount = dataSnapshot.child("coinsAmount").getValue(Long.class);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(coinsAmount));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
0
```

Comment: Thank you, could you advise me where I can read about this? but not in official documentation

Comment: Why "getValue(Long.class)" not "getValue(int.class)"

Comment: There is no `int.class`. Every number in a Firebase realtime database is a long and to get it as an int, you need to cast it to an int. So does the above code work?

Comment: For the first error please see my updated answer and for the second, are you sure you have the right dependencies added in your gradle file?

Comment: in build.gradle I have 3 dependencies: implementation of 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-auth: 16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-database: 16.0.1'

Comment: It's correct. In that case, please show me how this error `Cannot resolve symbol 'addListenerForSingleValueEvent` looks like in Android Studio, as a screenshot.

Comment: I see now, all that code should be added in the `onCreate()` method (inside the above curly brace) not outside the method. Does it work now?

Comment: So could you please throw off more information about Firebase Database because I still want to link the database to Recycler View

Comment: Specifically some sort of link to the source

Comment: Yes, sure. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot